# I have numpy but still getting "No module called 'numpy'"

Tags: python

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
and i have python 3.6 version and python3-numpy is also installed and the version is 1.13.3 but still while using some programs i'm getting following error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in 
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

I have tried updating and reinstalling the python3-numpy and all the other ways to rectify this issue.
what should i do ? please help !!

Comment: Can you be more specific than "using some programs"? Perhaps they use python2 not python3?

Answer (score 1):

Restart your computer. If you installed numpy with `pip install numpy` , it installed on your default python version. 
Try to execute it with python3

Answer (score 1):

You have installed the python3-numpy package from the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories. Enter into command mode with the `-c` option of python3 to check if you can indeed import numpy in python3.

```
python3 -c "import numpy"
```

Another way of making sure that you are running python3 is to start the python3 interpreter using the command `python3` and then run `import numpy` from the python3 prompt.